# Binding WPF TextBlock to custom object in application

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In MainWindow.xaml I have

```
...
<TextBlock x:Name="tbCpu" Text="{Binding Path=activeTower.cpuTotal}" />
...
```

and in MainWindow.xaml.cs I have

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Tower activeTower
    public MainWindow()
    {
        activeTower = Tower();
        activeTower.cpuTotal = 500;
        tbCpu.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine, without any errors.  However, tbCpu stays empty.  Tower is a custom class that has a property cpuTotal that returns a double, but I have tried other properties in the same class that return a string and it still doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`activeTower` needs to be a public property for the binding to work:

```
public Tower activeTower{get;set;}
```

If you want changes of `activeTower` to be reflected in the View then you need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in your class

Comment: Derp.  I knew it was something simple, thank you!  Works perfectly!